# IntelliJ IDEA not allowing me to click the jar and see the contents

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, macos-mojave

I changed part of the class for janusgraph , and i generated the jar and pasted that jar in one of the project folder , but intellij when am open the jar it is not allowing me , see below screen shot , can any one please help

[image]

see that red colored jar it is not in the form of other jars , what might the  issue .

Comment: check your dependencies to confirm the jar is indeed there (and not erased by mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After copying the jar to libs folder, add it to the project/module as a library.

Right click the jar file --> Add as library --> select the required options and click ok.

After that you should be able to expand it.

Comment: you are really gr8 , it worked for me thanks rahul , thanks a lot